# C# Fetching data from external source using infinite loop for multiple attempts

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous

My application uses MongoDB and I need to connect to the server and fetch some critical data when the application launches. If the connection attempt fails, I need to ask the user if he wants to try again or shutdown the application.

So far I went with the following solution:

```
public async Task LoadCriticalData()
{
    bool IsBusy = true;
    CancellationTokenSource Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken Token = Source.Token;

    while (!Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await FetchCriticalData();

            IsBusy = false;

            Source.Cancel();
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            bool Retry = RequestUserInteraction();

            if (!Retry)
            {
                Source.Cancel();
                CloseApplication();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I really don't like infinite loops (never used them for years before) but looks like there is no other way to implement this.

Is this sufficient or this can be done in a better way?

Comment: Where's the infinite loop? I don't see any. All the loops in this flow rely on variables that are set based on method success/failure or user input. Nothing runs indefinitely unless the connection keeps failing and the user keeps requesting that the program retry the connection.

Comment: CancellationTokenSource seems unnecessary. Why not use a simple boolean flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally fine to retry an operation in a loop as long as there is some exit criteria. Either when the operation succeeds, or the operator selects to terminate the operation or application. In either case it is not truly an infinite loop.